# JQuery File Uploader = error 405 IIS8.5

Tags: jquery, file, http, uploader

I have a frustratingly annoying issue which I can't resolve and have checked LOTS of forum posts (including lots from stack overflow), and CANNOT find the resolution to the dreaded 405 error.

I'm using the JQuery plugin - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin - and have the most minimalistic page you can imagine to get it working, but each time I attempt to upload a file, in the console I get a message:

```
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
```

I've done lots of searching regarding HTTP verbs, and have edited my .asp configuration (as I'm still using Classic ASP), also added a .json one, edited some of the other ones to add POST,GET etc - but nothing works!  I always return a 405 error.

Has anyone actually resolved this issue?  I've seen plenty of fixes but none work for me.

Comment: Have you confirmed separate from your script that you can in fact to a POST to the url where it would submit to? Another possibility is that you have spaces in the submission URL that are not getting encoded properly. However, the jQuery upload plugin would likely handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lower versions of IE then try this

```
forceIframeTransport: true
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance; @jdewald I tried another ASP standalone script which worked perfectly submitting to that location, as for spaces - it's a possibility, I'll check that one.

Comment: I'm using Chrome only - this is for an intranet system and we deploy Chrome globally and don't use IE.